# Exterior derivative of differential forms as Fréchet derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-forms

Let's consider differential forms defined on a Riemannian manifold. Then the tangent bundle may be locally considered as a Banach space and the forms are real valued functions defined in a Banach space. Thus I think we can think of the Fréchet derivative of the differential forms. Does this coincide with the exterior derivative of the differential forms? I'm not so familiar with differential forms and manifolds. I know the rules to use them but am struggling to get an intuitive picture. So the correspondence is just a vague idea I have. I'd like to know whether this picture is plausible or wrong.

Comment: How exactly are you thinking of the tangent bundle (locally) as a Banach space? If interpreted literally then it would surely be finite-dimensional, so it seems like overkill to be using functional-analytic concepts when you're really just doing multivariable calculus. Do you actually mean something like the *space of $C^k$ sections* of the tangent bundle (or some exterior power thereof)?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis I mean just a metric space by Banach space. Of course, I'm consideting a finite dimensional space.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis The Frechet derivative of a function is a linear map approximating the function and a $k$-th order derivative can be interpreted as a $(k+1)$-linear map approximating one-lower order derivative which is a $k$-linear map. So it is similar to the exterior derivative of differential forms as the derivative is a multilinear map with one more argument. So my vague idea is that, if the exterior derivative can be interpreted as a kind of "linear approximation" (I'm not sure of this), it may have something to do with the concept of Frechet derivative.

Comment: No, this is not going to capture the skew-symmetric nature of differential forms. For example, the Frechet derivative of the $1$-form $df$, viewed as a vector-valued map, will not be $0$, but will incorporate the Hessian of $f$ as well.